# If will - sentence structure

Tags: conditional-constructions

Please read below an example:

> You should discuss with her the consequences of her providing consent.  **If** she ***will*** not provide consent, then you should consider whether you are able to continue to act without placing you in breach of any of the mandatory Principles.

From the book "Practical English Usage", I know that the structure "If [something] will" conveys the meaning like "If it is true now that...".  Here are the examples from that book:

> '**If** Ann ***won't*** be here on Thursday, we'd better cancel the meeting.'
>
> '**If** prices ***will*** really come down in a few months, I am not going to buy one now.'

Would you please explain whether the first example and the second set of examples come under the same rule?

How does the structure (in the second set of examples) differ from unreal conditionals ('**if**+**past simple**, **would** + **past participle**)?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it does not come under that rule, but is using *will* in the sense of *be willing to*.

I don't understand your question about unreal conditionals.

Comment: My question is - what is the difference between the structures in the examples and the structure 'if+past simple, would + past participle' in terms of grammar and meaning?

Comment: Could you please explore more on what you wrote here (in particular 'using will in the sense of be willing to'?